# SQL XML output limited number of records

Tags: sql-server, xml, element

I am trying to use SELECT statement and output data as XML Elements But when I run the script, the output is not the full result, it stops at the record 1600, I have more than 5K records in that statement that needs to output in XML.

Here is my code.

```
DECLARE @XMLSessionData  xml 

SET @XMLData=
(SELECT 
'Document' AS "Type",
'' AS "Account",
 Name AS "NameClass",
2 AS "CodeType",
LastName AS "UserName/FamilyName",
FirstName AS "UserName/GivenName",
'' AS "UserName/initials",
NumberQuery AS "QueryCount",
IDNumber AS "UserNumber",
UserAddress AS "UserAddress/AddressLine1",
'' AS "UserAddress/AddressLine2",
'' AS "UserAddress/AddressLine3",
City AS "UserAddress/City",
State AS "UserAddress/State",
'USA' AS "UserAddress/CountryCode",
UserZipCode AS "UserAddress/ZipCode",
FROM tbSessonDocuments 
FOR XML PATH ('Documet'), ELEMENTS)

SELECT @XMLSessionData
```

The output is correct I have used the validate the XML against the Schema but the number of records that it's able to output as XML is limited, now it works fine if **I decrease the number of elements** it grabs the full result

Comment: What is happening when you run just the `SELECT ... FROM tbl FOR XML ... without variable?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to adjust settings in SSMS.

Select in the menu Tools/Options/Query Results/SQL Server/Results to Grid.

Maximum Characters Retrieved

XML data: **Unlimited**.